# How can I do http request in Angular, and have functions that returns all elements of Json or just one?

Tags: json, angularjs, promise, angular-promise, angular-http

I'm new in Angular and Ionic,
and I want to build one factory that gets one Json from googleapis,
and contains two functions, one returns all the elements, and another that returns the element passing index in parameter.

I'm trying in this way:

Factory:

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])

.factory('Noticias', function($http,$q) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();                
        $http.get("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load", { params: { "v": "1.0", "q": "http://www.furg.br/bin/rss/noticias.php", "num":"10" } })
          .success(function(data) {
              entries = data.responseData.feed.entries;
              deferred.resolve(entries);
          })
          .error(function(data) {
              console.log("ERROR: " + data);
          });

  var noticias =  deferred.promise;
  console.log(noticias);
  return {
    all: function() {
      return noticias;
    },
    remove: function(noticia) {
      noticias.splice(noticias.indexOf(noticia), 1);
    },
    get: function(noticiaId) {
      for (var i = 0; i < noticias.length; i++) {
        if (noticias[i].id === parseInt(noticiaId)) {
          return noticias[i];
        }
      }
      return null;
    }
  };
});
```

I got this in console, but I want the just the "value" at controller.

```
Promise {$$state: Object, then: function, catch: function, finally: function}$$state: Object
status: 1
value: Array[10]
0: Object
1: Object
2: Object
3: Object
4: Object
5: Object
6: Object
7: Object
8: Object
9: Object
length: 10
__proto__: Array[0]
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: show the controller code used for the factory request... what you are logging is the promise you created. Need to use promise callback for the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`noticias` is a promise. And all your methods use it as if it was an array. It's not. It's a promise.

So, the method `get` for example should be

```
get: function(noticiaId) {
    return noticias.then(function(array) {
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i].id === parseInt(noticiaId)) {
                return array[i];
            }
        }
        return null;
    });
}
```

and the user of the get() method should use it like this:

```
service.get(i).then(function(element) {
    // do something with element
});
```

Also note that your way of defining the promise is an antipattern. If the http request fails, the `noticias` promise is never rejected. Use promise chaining:

```
var noticias = $http.get("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load", { params: { "v": "1.0", "q": "http://www.furg.br/bin/rss/noticias.php", "num":"10" } })
      .then(function(response) {
          return response.data.responseData.feed.entries;
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to do this:

```
app.factory('Noticias', function($http, $q) {
    var http_get_success_callback = function(data) {
        var entries = data.responseData.feed.entries;
        return entries;
    };

    var jsonData = $q.when($http.get("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load", { params: { "v": "1.0", "q": "http://www.furg.br/bin/rss/noticias.php", "num":"10" } }).then(http_get_success_callback));
    this.getAllNoticias = function() {
        return jsonData;
    }

    this.getIndexNoticia = function(index) {
        return jsonData[index];
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

***My solution :***
Based on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33023283/5424391

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])

.factory('Noticias', function($http,$q) {

  var noticias = $http.get("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load", { params: { "v": "1.0", "q": "http://www.furg.br/bin/rss/noticias.php", "num":"20" } })
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.data.responseData.feed.entries;
    });

  return {
    all: function() {
      return noticias.then(function(array){
        return array;
      });
    },
    get: function(noticiaIndex) {
    return noticias.then(function(array) {
        return array[parseInt(noticiaIndex)];        
    });
  }
  };
});
```